# Function returns a vector, how to minimize in via NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize function, that returns a vector of values,
and here is an error:

> setting an array element with a sequence

Code:

```
P = np.matrix([[0.3, 0.1, 0.2], [0.01, 0.4, 0.2], [0.0001, 0.3, 0.5]])  
Ps = np.array([10,14,5])

def objective(x):   
    x = np.array([x])
    res = np.square(Ps - np.dot(x, P)) 
    return res 

def main():
    x = np.array([10, 11, 15])
    print minimize(objective, x, method='Nelder-Mead')
```

At these values of P, Ps, x function returns [[ 47.45143225  16.81        44.89      ]]

Thank you for any advice

**UPD (full traceback)**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-125-9649a65940b0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Roark/Documents/Python Scripts/optimize.py', wdir='C:/Users/Roark/Documents/Python Scripts')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Roark/Documents/Python Scripts/optimize.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:/Users/Roark/Documents/Python Scripts/optimize.py", line 24, in main
    print minimize(objective, x, method='Nelder-Mead')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 413, in minimize
    return _minimize_neldermead(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 438, in _minimize_neldermead
    fsim[0] = func(x0)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**UPD2: function should be minimized (Ps is a vector)**

[image]

Comment: Please post the full Traceback.

Comment: @miindlek just updated my post

Answer (score 3):

If you want you resulting vector to be a vector containing only `0`s, you can use `fsolve` to do so. To do that will require modifying your objective function a little bit to get the input and output into the same shape:

```
import scipy.optimize as so
P = np.matrix([[0.3, 0.1, 0.2], [0.01, 0.4, 0.2], [0.0001, 0.3, 0.5]])  
Ps = np.array([10,14,5])

def objective(x):   
    x = np.array([x])
    res = np.square(Ps - np.dot(x, P)) 
    return np.array(res).ravel() 
Root = so.fsolve(objective, x0=np.array([10, 11, 15]))
objective(Root)
#[  5.04870979e-29   1.13595970e-28   1.26217745e-29]
```

Result: The solution is `np.array([ 31.95419775,  41.56815698, -19.40894189])`

Comment: +1 `fsolve` should have occurred to me! It's worth pointing, though, out that `fsolve` uses MINPACK [`hybrd.f`](http://www.netlib.org/minpack/hybrd.f) which minimizes the euclidean norm of the vector, so the actual 'objective function' used internally would be equivalent to the square root of mine. Loss functions still need to have a scalar output.

Answer (score 2):

Your objective function needs to return a scalar value, not a vector. You probably want to return the *sum* of squared errors rather than the vector of squared errors:

```
def objective(x):
    res = ((Ps - np.dot(x, P)) ** 2).sum()
    return res
```

Comment: I updated my post, there is a function to be minimized. It returns a vector, not a scalar value. Ps - is a vector.

Comment: @Rachnog Well... that's a problem. Your [loss function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) *always* has to return a scalar value that reflects the overall 'goodness' of the current parameter set. Suppose, for the moment, that the objective function returns a vector. I find that increasing `x[0]` reduces `objective(x)[0]` but increases `objective(x)[1]`. How should I update `x`?

Comment: I should think about it, maybe it's error in related article or I don't inderstand sense of Ps :)

Comment: Generally it is a poor advice to convert least squares problem to minimization of a scalar function, because this way the information about structure of x is lost and it may take much more iterations to converge, or it can fail to converge altogether

Answer (score 0):

Use [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html). This will require to modify the objective a bit to return differences instead of squared differences:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

P = np.matrix([[0.3, 0.1, 0.2], [0.01, 0.4, 0.2], [0.0001, 0.3, 0.5]])  
Ps = np.array([10,14,5])

def objective(x):
    x = np.array([x])
    res = Ps - np.dot(x, P)
    return np.asarray(res).flatten()

def main():
    x = np.array([10, 11, 15])
    print(least_squares(objective, x))
```

Result:

```
 active_mask: array([0., 0., 0.])
        cost: 5.458917464129402e-28
         fun: array([1.59872116e-14, 2.84217094e-14, 5.32907052e-15])
        grad: array([-8.70414856e-15, -1.25943700e-14, -1.11926469e-14])
         jac: array([[-3.00000002e-01, -1.00000007e-02, -1.00003682e-04],
       [-1.00000001e-01, -3.99999999e-01, -3.00000001e-01],
       [-1.99999998e-01, -1.99999999e-01, -5.00000000e-01]])
     message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 4
        njev: 4
  optimality: 1.2594369966691647e-14
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([ 31.95419775,  41.56815698, -19.40894189])
```

Answer (score 0):

[yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25201504/15893581)

> At these values of P, Ps, x function returns [[ 47.45143225 16.81
> 44.89 ]]

[res](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25208202/15893581)

> Result: The solution is np.array([ 31.95419775,  41.56815698,
> -19.40894189])

what result you really need? your ValueError shows some problem in shapes of variables, you can adopt your own code, like this:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

P = np.matrix([[0.3, 0.1, 0.2], [0.01, 0.4, 0.2], [0.0001, 0.3, 0.5]])
Ps = np.array([10,14,5])

def objective(x):
    res = np.square(Ps - np.dot(x, P)).sum()    # <<<<< sum
    return res

def main():
    x = np.array([10, 11, 15])
    res=  minimize(objective, x, method='Nelder-Mead')
    print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but still **result** is like in fsolve_Solution (provided above), not as you pointed in your open_topic_message

```
final_simplex: (array([[ 31.95415651,  41.5681525 , -19.40893553],
       [ 31.95421376,  41.56815815, -19.40892458],
       [ 31.95417772,  41.56820834, -19.40895555],
       [ 31.9541516 ,  41.56814833, -19.40890433]]), array([2.05803682e-10, 2.22144587e-10, 2.39097188e-10, 2.65258467e-10]))
           fun: 2.0580368213652934e-10
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 167
           nit: 92
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([ 31.95415651,  41.5681525 , -19.40893553])
```